# How to use Composition instead of Inheritance?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a `Configurator` class that, in order to do its work, must receive a `Context` object via an interface:

```
public class Configurator : IContextAware
{
    private IContext _context;

    //property setter defined by the IContextAware interface
    public IContext Context { set { _context = value; } }

    //  use _context object in other methods here ...
}
```

I plan to write MANY `Configurator` types, which will all need to initalize their `_context` fields the same way. My first thought was "Why not anger every programmer on the Internet and use inheritance"?

```
public class ContextInitializer: IContextAware
{
    // field to hold the injected context
    protected IContext _context;

    //property setter defined by the IContextAware interface
    public IContext Context { set { _context = value; } }
}

public class Configurator : ContextInitializer
{
    //  use _context object here ...
}
```

This way, any other classes I write that need a Context object can just inherit from ContextInitializer, and use the Context object straight away.

Pros: guaranteed consistent initialization, no distracting, duplicated initialize code in every class

Cons: Implementation inheritance is evil!,.. um, Configurator cannot inherit from any other class.. ??

I should clarify that one way or another, Configurator MUST implement the `IContextAware` interface. ALSO, the class must have a default/no-arg constructor, so constructor dependency injection is not an option here.

Can someone suggest how Composition can be used to achieve the same benefits, but with more flexible design, and/or describe the real short-comings of the Inheritance solution above? Thanks!

P.S. This is adapted from Spring.Net CodeConfig, if anyone is curious.

Comment: Inheritance is evil? I missed that memo.

Comment: @Rik http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steverowe/archive/2008/04/28/prefer-composition-over-inheritance.aspx http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2003/jw-0801-toolbox.html http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ImplementationInheritanceIsEvil     In truth, If I were asked "Is `Configurator` a `ContextInitializer`? I would have to say no, but USES the `ContextInitalizer`, thus suggesting inheritance is not quite right here.

Comment: Absolute statements are *always* wrong. Inheritance isn't inherently evil. It's a tool. you can use a hammer to put a nail into a wall or to crack open someones skull. It's how you use it, that could be evil.

Comment: OK, so _misuse_ of inheritance is evil. Got it.

Comment: @user1467261 - you are right, `Configurator` *uses* a `ContextInitializer`. So why not have the constructor be `public Configurator(IContextInitializer contextInitializer) { // use contextInitializer }`? (btw. if you plan on having different kinds of context initializers, I'd strongly suggest using an Interface) - a good example is in the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: @Corak -"Absolute statements are always wrong" - that sounds pretty absolute to me. Sorry, couldn't resist:) But seriously, thanks - will give it a shot.

Comment: Note the *italic*. ^_^ - and no, in this case, as you said, `Configurator` is *not* a `ContextInitializer`, so it shouldn't inherit from it.

Comment: On the other hand, every class that *does* have an `IContext` property *could* maybe inherit from the same (abstract) class. So you wouldn't have to define that property in every class. But you know your class hierarchy better to decide if that's a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think the .NET Base Class Library is a good standard** to answer such questions. Your use of inheritance **would have never been put into the BCL** because it exposes the user of your API to API internals. There is now a base class that does not have any semantic meaning. It only exists to save code. All public API elements should have a purpose and semantic meaning.

The authors of the BCL are obviously very strict when it comes to API design. I have never seen such a huge yet pristine collection of types.

That said, you don't need to adhere to the same standards if you don't need that level of API cleanliness. **Not every API is exposed to millions of developers.** It is a legitimate **trade-off** to compromise on API purity a little to save lots of code and to remove redundancy and potential for errors.

**My choice**: I'd use your approach for internal code. For public APIs (think of Codeplex libraries and so on) I'd rather duplicate the redundant stuff and keep the public API surface clean.